# How to integrate the ASP.NET thread model and ZeroMQ sockets?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis-7, zeromq

I'm building an ASP.NET service (a simple aspx) that requires a REQ call to a ZeroMQ REP node.

So I've to use the REQ/REP pattern, but I can't figure out the proper way to initialize the ZeroMQ context in the ASP.NET pipeline.

Moreover, can I share a single connection among the different ASP.NET threads and if so how?

**edit**: After some study it looks to me that an [inproc router](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Shared-Queue-DEALER-and-ROUTER-sockets) in a dedicated thread should be the way to go, since it would handle sincronization.

But more questions arise:

1. The other end of such an inproc node should be a DEALER? If so, should it connect to the REQ node? Or it should bind to a tcp port and I should code the REP server node to connect to it (the latter would be a bit cumbersome, since I could have different servers exposing the service)?
2. As an alternative, is it correct to build an inproc node bound to a ROUTER socket at one end, and connecting with REQ on the other? If so, should I code the node so that it handles a manual envelop of each message just to be able to send responses back to the correct requesting thread?
3. Is Application_Start the correct pipeline point to initialize the thread handling such router?

At the moment a ROUTER/DEALER inproc node that connect to the REQ server looks like the best option, but I'm not sure that it's possibile to **connect** from a DEALER socket. But this is still just a speculation and could be entirely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The [zmq_socket manual](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-socket) states:

> ØMQ sockets are not thread safe. Applications MUST NOT use a socket
>   from multiple threads except  after migrating a socket from one thread
>   to another with a "full fence" memory barrier.

Comment: 1) what about the context?
2) so I've to connect() at the request begin and close the socket at the end?